# getting inconsistent output between two methods of reversing a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists, experimental-design

I am trying to run a counter balancing program. I cannot understand what Python is doing to get the output I receive. I have 8 variants of 16 maps. Variants are defined by `timingConditions` * `distractionConditions`. There are 4 key parts of the initial variable definitions:

1. `inst` is a list containing all 8 variants * 16 experimental maps
   ordered by variant (the maps are literally like a video game map). This leaves `len(inst) = 128`.
2. `inst` is subdivided into 8 sublists in `conds`. Each of these
   sublists represents maps 1-16 of a specific variant. Each index
   within a sublist represts one map/variant combination. Calling the index of each sublist in `conds` will show you this clearly.
3. The 16 maps are broken into 8 lists containing two maps each, defined in variable `MapGroups`. These 8 lists are for use in the matrix below.
4. `counterBalanceMatrix` represents eight unique balanced orderings of maps to condition assignment. Each subject in `range(1,9)` is assigned to one of these rows. The numbers in the row represent map groups. Columns (i.e. index ordering) represent assignment of variant to map group. For example, `counterBalanceMatrix[0][0]` returns `1`, the first index corresponds to assignment of first variant column `SSTrue`; and second index corresponds to `MapGroups[0]` (which would return '0','15'). Therefore, the desired output would be maps 0 and 15 (or 1 and 16 without zero based ordering) are assigned SS-True. You can picture this as follows:

   ```
           ####+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
           ####| SSTrue | SLTrue | LSTrue | LLTrue | SSFalse | SLFalse | LSFalse | LLFalse |
           ####+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
           ####|      1 |      2 |      3 |      4 |       5 |       6 |       7 |       8 |
           ####|      2 |      3 |      4 |      5 |       6 |       7 |       8 |       1 |
           ####|      3 |      4 |      5 |      6 |       7 |       8 |       1 |       2 |
           ####|      4 |      5 |      6 |      7 |       8 |       1 |       2 |       3 |
           ####|      5 |      6 |      7 |      8 |       1 |       2 |       3 |       4 |
           ####|      6 |      7 |      8 |      1 |       2 |       3 |       4 |       5 |
           ####|      7 |      8 |      1 |      2 |       3 |       4 |       5 |       6 |
           ####|      8 |      1 |      2 |      3 |       4 |       5 |       6 |       7 |
           ####+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+---------+-----  ----+
   ```

The expected output of the code below that for `subject in range(1,9):`, there will be one instance of each `MapGroup`, and two observations of each variant (e.g. SS-TRUE, LL-False etc). Across all subjects, there will be equal observations of all `MapGroups` and variants. **This part of the code works as expected**.

```
import re
timingConditions = ["SS","SL","LS","LL"]
distractionConditions = ["True","False"]
maps = [i for i in range(1,17)]

#This loop sets up the 128 (16*8) variants. Inst for instances of scenario.
inst = []
for d in distractionConditions:
    for t in timingConditions:
        for map in maps:
            inst.append(str(str(map)+"-"+t+"-"+d))

conds = [inst[0:16],inst[16:32],inst[32:48],inst[48:64],inst[64:80],inst[80:96],inst[96:112],inst[112:128]]

MapGroups= [[0,8],
[1,9],
[2,10],
[3,11],
[4,12],
[5,13],
[6,14],
[7,15]]

counterBalanceMatrix= [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1],
[3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2],
[4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3],
[5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4],
[6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5],
[7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6],
[8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]]

for subject in range(1,9):
    cRow = counterBalanceMatrix[(subject-1)%8]#Use the modulus operator to find out which row to use in counterbalancing for this subject.
    scenArray = []

    for group in range(0,8):#This loops across map groups and look up their assigned interruption condition
        scenArray.extend([conds[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in MapGroups[group]]) 
        print "****","Participant",subject,"Correct Day 1****"
        print scenArray
        print "\n\n"
```

**This is where the problem is:**
I want to repeat this procedure, but mirrored. That is, whatever variant each `list in MapGroups` was assigned initially, I want it to be inversed (e.g. If you received `MapGroups[0]` as True, then I want them to be False. `MapGroups[0]` was assigned SS, it now must be LL.

My initial solution was to reverse the `counterBalanceMatrix` and apply the same Loop. However this did not work:

```
counterBalanceMatrixReverse= []
for list in counterBalanceMatrix:
    counterBalanceMatrixReverse.append(list[::-1])

###And then run the exact same loop over.
for subject in range(1,9):
    cRow = counterBalanceMatrixReverse[(subject-1)%8]
#
    scenArray = []
    for group in range(0,8):
        scenArray.extend([conds[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in MapGroups[group]])
        print "****","Participant",subject,"Broken Reversed 2****"
        print scenArray
        print "\n\n"
```

The output is incorrect, for instance:

```
>Participant 4 
>'2-SL-True', '10-SL-True'
Participant 4 Reversed
>'2-SS-False', '10-SS-False'
Exptected Reversed Ouput:
>'2-LS-False', '10-LS-False'
```

**However, the simply reversing the cond array does solve my problem**

```
condsreverse = []
condsreverse.extend(conds[::-1])

for subject in range(1,9):
    cRow = counterBalanceMatrix[(subject-1)%8]#Note I use same matrix
    scenArray = []
    for group in range(0,8):
        scenArray.extend([condsreverse[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in MapGroups[group]]) 
    print "****","Subject",subject,"Correct Reverse****"
    print scenArray
    print "\n\n"
```

I have sat on this now for three days, and I can't work out why the initial reversing solution does not produce the desired output.

Comment: Hmm, but why does reversing the rows not also reverse the index assignment in `[condsreverse[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in MapGroups[group]]`

Comment: Hrm, I must say I am getting thoroughly confused between the various matrices you have in your code, and what is being reversed where.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have two instances of reversal which can be treated as separate. As you mention, in one, I reverse the columns, and in the other I reverse the rows. The 2nd snippet I reverse rows in the matrix by reversing lists. The 3rd snippet I reverse columns.

 However, if you picture reversing the rows, then this should have the same effect as column reversal. Yet, I am getting two different outputs depending on which one I do. Clearly, my row reversal procedure is flaw, but I have debugged it and can't work out why.

Answer (score 1):

I believe solution is as follows, if only for the purpose of closing question.

My mistake was that I assumed the `[conds[cRow[group]-1]` was assigning the variant based on the index of the `cRow[i]` and the `cRow[i]` was simply being used to call the specific maps. However, what is actually doing is assigning the variant based on the value of `cRow[i]`. Consequently, the "columns" were not being assigned to `MapGroups` based on indexing. This means that simply reversing the `counterBalanceMatrix` is basically just creating another version of the `counterBalanceMatrix`.

The only way I can get the conditions to mirror each other is by reversing the order of `conds` because this the list which is actually being used in the assignment; unless of course I wanted to change `scenArray.extend([condsreverse[cRow[group]-1][i] for i in MapGroups[group]])` to call index of each item (for both the original and reversed), and then based on that index call the map group, as follows:

```
for index in range(0,8):
    scenArray.extend([conds[index][i] for i in MapGroups[cRow[index]-1]])
```

*PS: I guess writing it out as a question helped me realize my fault. Sorry for this.*

Comment: You just discovered [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).